# Can SQLite be used when a program was written with mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

i'm copying a series of examples from  Robin Nixon's Learning PHP, javascript and MySql

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-MySQL-JavaScript-Step-Step/dp/0596157134/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596157134)

which ultimatly unite to form a basic social networking site. All of these examples are written in php, javscript and mySql. At some point I would like to use SQLite instead of mySql. My question is, will i be able to finish the site in mysql and then simply began using SQLite, or will other steps be be needed, such as rewriting the whole thing?

Comment: Unless you are using an [ODBC data connector](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) (such as ADO) to generate your sql, you will have to rewrite your sql to work in other database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unless you are using an abstraction layer, you will need to switch to a different API for using the completely different database.

Next, you are probably using some MySQL specific functions that will need to be worked around.

Finally, work around anything not implemented in SQLite.

I'd really be curious to know **why** you want want to do this anyway.  Do you understand that SQLite databases really aren't meant for a lot of concurrent connections, and aren't generally considered appropriate for websites of any decently sized scale?

Comment: I thought sqlite doesn't support more than 1 concurrent connection, period.

Comment: @bdares that is technically true, but I believe there is some locking mechanism that simulates the ability to have multiple "connections".  Perhaps someone with more familiarity with SQLite can clarify.

Comment: SQLite supports as many read-connections as the system can handle, but a write, *any* write, will lock the *whole* database until committed. So it's multi-user for read-operations, single-user while writing. For write-once-read-many type of websites, SQLite is actually quite nice.

Comment: With "shared-cache mode" enabled, SQLite tolerates concurrent reads to tables *not* being written to. As you note, only one transaction-level write lock can be acquired at a time, so that means that only one connection can acquire a write lock, but some amount of concurrent reading is accommodated for connections using the same shared cache. More: http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html

Comment: what i'm gathering from this answer and comments is that SQLite is not appropriate for a social networking site because a social networking site would require more then one concurrent connection? is 'concurrent connection' synonymous with 'concurrent query'?

Comment: @expiredninja, in this case, yes.